# Basic topological sequence question

Tags: general-topology

Let $x_n=n, \space \space n\geq 1 $ be a sequence in the topological space $X=\Bbb N$ and $T$ be the collection of all subsets whose compliment is finite and $\emptyset $.

Now i believe that the sequence converges to every point in X because for each set there is a largest element not in that set. for example i can write down an infinite number of sets containing 1 this seems to imply that the sequence approach one. how do i prove this?

Edit:
For every open set A containing $1$ there is a greatest element not in A call it d let $N= d+1$ then for all $n \geq N$ the sequence $x_n$ is entirely contained in A so the sequence converges to 1.

However 1 was an arbitrarily chosen element the same statement works for any number you wish to place there from $\Bbb N$ so i believe $x_n$ converges to every point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct for your chosen sequence $x_n=n$, and can generalize what you've found somewhat. 
Let $X$ be any infinite set, $\mathcal{T}_{cf}$ be the cofinite topology as you've defined it, $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence that assumes infinitely many values, and $x^*$ be an arbitrary point in $X$. Then for every $A \in \mathcal{T}_{cf}$ with $x^* \in A$, we have that $X-A$ contains finitely many elements. Since $\{x_n\}$ assumes infintely many values, we can avoid all of the finitely many elements in $X-A$ by picking a significantly large $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n \geq N$ we have $x_n \not\in X-A$. That is,  for $n \geq N$ we have $x_n \in A$. Since infinitely many elements of the sequence are in $A$, we have $x_n \to x^*$.

See the answer by José Carlos Santos for what happens if your sequence assumes finitely many values.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. If each $x_n$ is $2$, then the sequence does *not* converge to $1$. In fact, $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{2\}$ is a neigborhood of $1$ which contains no $x_n$

Comment: for every open set U containing 1 there is a greatest element not in U call it d let N= d+1 then for all n> N the sequence $x_n$ is entirely contained in U so the sequence converges to 1.
Sorry i edited the question for more clarity does it seem more reasonable now?

Comment: @Faust The question was perfectly clear the first time I read it. The complement of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{2\}$ is finite and therefore $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{2\}$ is an open set. Furthermore, $1\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{2\}$. So, $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{2\}$ is a neighborhood of $1$, to which $2$ does not belong. Therefore, the sequence that I defined dos *not* converge to $1$.

Comment: Right, thanks for being so helpful.